# Мобильное приложение для работы с интернетом, сетями

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Посоветуйте, какое приложение написать , чтобы освоить хорошо все что связано с интенетом и сетями (протоколы передачи, взаимодействие по сети и так далее).
То есть чтобы была освоить возможность синхронизации, допустим , с сервисами по сети. 
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Тестовое задание в бывшей конторе было написать rss reader. Как раз всё освоите)